# Quebrar linha (clearfix)

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber, quais formas vocês utilizam quando precisam que um elemento, ocupe a WIDTH+HEIGHT total que ele esta utilizando, por exemplo:

```
<p>
    <span>Teste</span>
</p>
```

Para que o **P** ocupe o tamanho total que esta utilizando, eu costumo utilizar uma classe chamada **cb**, com as seguintes propriedades:

```
.cb {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

ou o próprio clearfix, porém, sempre fico me perguntando se existe uma forma mais organizada de se fazer.

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, o elemento `<p>` já é um elemento de bloco, e por isso já assume todo o tamanho do seu conteúdo (width + height)

Comment: Acho que o exemplo não ficou muito claro, mas por exemplo, se eu tivesse 2 SPAN's dentro do P, e desse float: left; nos mesmos, os elementos que viessem após o P, provavelmente iriam ficar na mesma linha dos SPAN's. Para evitar isso, usaria a classe CB no P.

Comment: Só o `overflow: hidden` já basta.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer com `float` ou com `display: inline-block`, ou `inline-table` e se não for flutuante da para usar `display: block`.