# Ajuste de layout com elementos que que são gerados automáticamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5, css3

Estou fazendo um site em que uma das páginas é responsável por listar as publicações do usuário em forma de caixas. Cada caixa corresponde a uma nova publicação do usuário, que é gerada pelo código em  ASP.NET MVC 4 com Entity Framework 6 automaticamente, pegando as informações do banco. Duplicando as *divs* no *html* e a formatação do *layout* dessas *divs* em *css*, amostrando e criando *links*, tudo perfeito.

Mas quando é inserido uma nova caixa de publicação, ela vai para baixo da anterior e eu queria que ficasse do lado e fosse descendo com *css*.

Utilizei uma *tag* em *css* que é *float:left*, porém a *div* central do corpo da página não fica com a *height* responsiva quando um elemento é *float*, pois para mantê-la responsiva eu não defini a altura, só defini um *padding-bottom*.

Queria saber como faço para as caixas irem pro lado direito e descerem conforme forem geradas automaticamente e manter responsivo a *height* do corpo da página?

Exemplo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro que alteres a tua questão e a tornes mais intuitiva e de fácil leitura, esta bem confuso... Aproveita e acrescenta código que possa ser relevante

Comment: Se bem entendi, pois ta extremamente confusa sua pergunta, você quer que se layout seja responsivo certo ? Antes mais nada, qual a versão do *MVC* ? Porque de uns tempos pra cá, o *MVC* já vem com o *bootstrap* cara. Aprende a parte de *grids* que vai te ajudar nessa sua questão. Mas de qualquer forma, põe os códigos que já fez ?

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um problema um tanto complexo envolvendo o CSS da aplicação. [É um dos problemas que o Bootstrap se propõe a resolver](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Grosso modo, o que você precisa fazer é o seguinte:

```
.minha_div_celula {
    width: 33.33333333%;
    float: left;
}
```

Além disso, a `<div>` que comporta as `<div>` filhas deve ter algo como:

```
.div_mae {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

[Pode ser necessário usar uma `<div>` de clearfix](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31311/quebrar-linha-clearfix) para fazer o browser entender que as `<div>` filhas acabaram, e que uma nova `<div>` deve ser gerada fora do conjunto anterior mãe-filhas.

[Tenho uma estamparia cujo site implementa exatamente isso que você quer fazer](http://www.tecelariadoppel.com.br/).

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução bem simples seria colocar o estilo `overflow: hidden` no elemento que é o contêiner dos blocos. E para estes blocos, usar o `float: left`.

Veja nesse exemplo se é o que você quer:

```js
var conteiner = document.getElementById("conteiner");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    conteiner.innerHTML += "<div class='bloco'></div>"
});
```

```css
.bloco {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 8px solid red;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
}
#conteiner {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 240px;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
Clique no botão para adicionar vários blocos sucessivamente.<br/>
<button id="btn">Adicionar novo bloco</button>
<div id="conteiner">
    <div class='bloco'></div>
</div>
```